# how to replace this case statement with a subquery

Tags: sql, case

```
CASE
           WHEN(CASE
                    WHEN ISNULL(VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId, 0) > 0
                         AND VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1
                    THEN ISNULL(CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents, 0) + 1  
                    WHEN ISNULL(VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId, 0) > 0
                    THEN ISNULL(CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents, 0)
                    WHEN VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END - ISNULL((COM.OutreachCount + COM.FVMsgCount), 0)) < 0
           THEN 0
           ELSE(CASE
                    WHEN ISNULL(VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId, 0) > 0
                         AND VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1
                    THEN ISNULL(CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents, 0) + 1 
                    WHEN ISNULL(VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId, 0) > 0
                    THEN ISNULL(CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents, 0)
                    WHEN VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END - ISNULL((COM.OutreachCount + COM.FVMsgCount), 0))
       END AS EventsRemaining,
       CASE
           WHEN ISNULL(VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId, 0) > 0
                AND VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1
           THEN ISNULL(CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents, 0) + 1  
           WHEN ISNULL(VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId, 0) > 0
           THEN ISNULL(CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents, 0)
           WHEN VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END AS ExpectedNumofEvents,
```

I have a logic like below inside my **View**. How to replace this case statement with a shorter way or any subquery without writing multiple times the same logic, how can i store in any variable and how to do this in View. Please help me to fix this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: For one improvement, you can remove a lot of the `ISNULL()` expressions. For example, `NULL < 0` is never `true`. `ISNULL(VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId, 0) > 0` is also not true if `VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId` is NULL. So you can just remove the `ISNULL()` check.

Comment: Those are `case` _expressions_, not statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one improvement, you can remove some of the `ISNULL()` expressions.

For example, `NULL > 0` is never `true`. Therefore the
`ISNULL(VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId, 0) > 0` expression in the first `WHEN` clause is also never `true` if `VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId` is `NULL`.

This can sometimes get you into trouble, because it's also not exactly `false`. However, a `WHEN` expression will also not match a `NULL` boolean result, so we're safe here to remove the `ISNULL()` check completely, leaving us with this:

```
VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId > 0
```

We now apply this and can further look at these two `WHEN`/`THEN` expressions:

```
WHEN VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId > 0
             AND VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1
    THEN ISNULL(CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents, 0) + 1  
WHEN VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId > 0
    THEN ISNULL(CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents, 0)
```

Notice they both have the **same** `THEN` result, except the former adds one.

This is almost redundant, and I think we can factor out the `AND VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1` check.

Put both adjustments together, and I think this:

```
CASE
    WHEN ISNULL(VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId, 0) > 0
         AND VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1
    THEN ISNULL(CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents, 0) + 1  
    WHEN ISNULL(VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId, 0) > 0
    THEN ISNULL(CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents, 0)
    WHEN VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
```

reduces to this:

```
CASE WHEN VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId > 0 
     THEN ISNULL(CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents, 0)
     ELSE 0 END
 + CASE WHEN VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Or this:

```
COALESCE(CASE WHEN VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId > 0 
              THEN CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents END, 0)
 + CASE WHEN VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

And now we spread this through the rest of the excerpt:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN COALESCE(CASE WHEN VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId > 0 
                       THEN CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents END, 0)
                   + CASE WHEN VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           < ISNULL(COM.OutreachCount + COM.FVMsgCount, 0) 
    THEN 0
    ELSE COALESCE(CASE WHEN VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId > 0 
                       THEN CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents END, 0)
                    + CASE WHEN VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                    - ISNULL(COM.OutreachCount + COM.FVMsgCount, 0)
END AS EventsRemaining,
COALESCE(CASE WHEN VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId > 0 
              THEN CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents END, 0)
 + CASE WHEN VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ExpectedNumofEvents,
```

You could, of course, also further reduce things by nesting the this in another SELECT query, so this result is a computed column.

Comment: the above code works perfectly. Thanks a lot @joel Coehoorn

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN EventsRemaining < 0 THEN 0
        ELSE EventsRemaining
    END AS EventsRemaining,
    ExpectedNumofEvents
FROM (
    SELECT
        (CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId, 0) > 0 AND VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1 THEN ISNULL(CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents, 0) + 1
            WHEN ISNULL(VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId, 0) > 0 THEN ISNULL(CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents, 0)
            WHEN VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END - ISNULL((COM.OutreachCount + COM.FVMsgCount), 0)) AS EventsRemaining,
        (CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId, 0) > 0 AND VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1 THEN ISNULL(CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents, 0) + 1
            WHEN ISNULL(VEH.DriverOutreachProfileId, 0) > 0 THEN ISNULL(CPP.ExpectedNumberofEvents, 0)
            WHEN VEH.FVMessagingInd = 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS ExpectedNumofEvents
    FROM YourTable
) AS SubqueryAlias;
```

In this query, I've created a subquery that calculates EventsRemaining and ExpectedNumofEvents only once and then applied the CASE statement to EventsRemaining in the outer query. This makes the SQL code cleaner and more maintainable. Make sure to replace YourTable with the actual table name you are working with.